# Android Studio - the application has stopped

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener

I'm trying Android Studio. I've created a simple app with a button with `onClickLister()` to show a Toast message. I get the message "the application has stopped".

-The same code works with Eclipse
-I created more projects to try
-tried on virtual and real device
-Reinstalled Android Studio

Any idea?

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity Class here :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button mibtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    mibtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Apretado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Logcat:

```
01-14 12:43:11.759    5651-5651/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41538ba8)
01-14 12:43:11.759    5651-5651/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.omaxlive.myapplicationtest, PID: 5651
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.omaxlive.myapplicationtest/com.omaxlive.myapplicationtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.omaxlive.myapplicationtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post LogCat trace for crash?

Comment: It seems that you are working in a fragment. onCreate might be called before the actual view is created and toast might give you trouble on that. Try moving them to onCreateView. If not it is probably a reference problem and you need to clean your project and set your references again. Edit: My bad, it is on the click event so there won't be a context problem, it is probably with the references.

Comment: What do you have in MainActivity.java:25 line

Comment: line25: mibtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... @Niko

Comment: Very weird crash, maybe Android Studio somehow compiles the package wrong, since it works with Eclipse built package.

Comment: @benLIVE post the xml in which you have the buton

Comment: XML posted @Raghunandan

Comment: @benLIVE xml posted is `activity_main.xml` . also read the caution here http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html. if you are not comfortable using studio switch to eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Line shows that the Button you have created is in `fragment_main.xml`

```
 tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
```

But you are finding your button in `activity_main.xml`

Move your code from `onCreate()` to `onCreateView` of PlaceholderFragment like

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    Button mibtn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

    mibtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Apretado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
});

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are finding your layout on:

```
setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
```

but your layout which you are using is fragment_main.xml

so change `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);`

and secondly delete this code from your .java file

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
            .commit();
}
```